# Refresh page and previously selected file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html document that allows the user to select a (local) file using the input element (click "browse..." go to document location click "open")

```
<input type="file" name="xlfile" id="xlf" onchange="setTimeout(myFunction, 1000)"/>
```

This file is then sent to a javascript which outputs data on the webpage.

I need the site to refresh every 5-10 min and resend the document to the javascript in order for the user to monitor changes to the selected file, but every refresh command I have tried has ignored the previously inputted file and it has to be reselected.

Is there a way for this to be done using html or javascript?

Comment: You could try to output your data into an iframe and recreate it's content every 5-10min...

Comment: Do you really need to refresh the whole web page ?

Comment: i would use setInterval

Comment: Hamza Abdaoui the webpage only contains the input button and the output of the file from the JS

Comment: if you want to reload whole page, you'll need to save selected file somewhere, I don't know if it is possible, so i would write setInterval(myFunction, 1000 * 60 * 5); and rewrite output every time it trigers

Comment: setInterval would rerun the script but how would you get it to reload the document?

Comment: "in order for the user to monitor changes to the selected file" - what "changes" exactly? Your app flow seems a little weird to me...

Comment: Fahmi the selected file is automatically generated by a computer in a different building. Every time a new test is done on a production batch the results are appended at the end of the file, which should then appear on page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a reload function that keeps reloading your page every 5 minutes.

```css
function reload() {
  setTimeout(function () {
   location.reload();
  }, (300 * 1000));
 }
});
```

By the way now the site is reloading each 5 minutes. You must call the function a the start from your javascript file.

Comment: The site will reload after 5 minutes = 300 * 1000 is equal to five minutes so you just have to wait

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" name="xlfile" id="xlf" onchange="myFunction();"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction()
  {
    var file = $("#xlf").val();
    console.log(file);
    /* wright here your code */
    setInterval(myFunction, 5000);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: how would 
     "var file = $("#xlf").val();"

look like in regular javascript and not jquery

Comment: var file = document.getElementById("xlf").value;

Comment: I get a "C:\fakepath\filename.filetype" and nothing happens to the script, still reloads at the set time, but only ever get the fakepath message